# Understanding the Probability Outcomes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

A eight sided dice is rolled thrice and the first roll was an odd number. If the selected roll in random is odd what is the probability?

Total number of possible outcomes when a die is rolled thrice = $8^{3}$ = 512

Favorable Outcome = ${8 \choose 4} * {8 \choose 8} * {8 \choose 8} $ = 70

Probability of getting a odd number is = 70 / 512

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: One thing to check: Is the answer reasonable? Without the information of the first roll being odd, the probability of choosing an odd number would be $\frac12$ (assuming the die is fair). Now knowing that the first roll was definitely odd, it seems that the probability of selecting an odd roll would go up (not go down).

Comment: @paw88789 What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: What exactly is the space of possible outcomes? There are more "choices" that have to be considered; in particular, we need another independent choice representing which roll was selected. But note that all of these "outcomes" do not have equal probability --- for instance, we will never roll 6,5,5 and choose the third dice.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your binomial coefficients are representing, but I don't think it's the number of favorable outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clear way to think about a problem like this, based on conditional probability.

Let event $A$ be the case where you select (randomly) the first roll, and let event $B$ be the case where you select the second or third. These two events are complementary. Let event $C$ be the favorable outcome (we randomly select a roll with an odd outcome). The Law of Total Probability states that $$\Pr[C] = \Pr[C|A]\cdot\Pr[A] + \Pr[C|B]\cdot\Pr[B]$$ (where by $\Pr[X|Y]$ we mean the probability that the event $X$ happens, given that $Y$ happens).

Now $\Pr[A] = ⅓$ and $\Pr[B] = ⅔$, since the random choice of which roll we look at is independent of everything else. On the other hand, $\Pr[C|A] = 1$, since we are guaranteed the first roll is odd; $\Pr[C|B] = ½$ since the die is fair. So we can calculate $\Pr[C]$.

Comment: So the total possible outcomes don't play a role here. the event is based on the selection of the roll.

Comment: There is an underlying set of possible outcomes, each of which occurs with equal probability, representing "Dice 1 rolled X, Dice 2 rolled Y, Dice 3 rolled Z, we saw dice N". But what probability are we trying to find? The probability of seeing an odd number, GIVEN that Dice 1 rolled an odd number. So to use a "total outcomes" approach, we must calculate: (# of outcomes where we see an odd number) / (# of outcomes where Dice 1 is odd).

Comment: If I want to check for the probability that all the three rolls have a number greater than 5 then the Favorable Outcome would be = ${8 \choose 3} * {8 \choose 3} * {8 \choose 3} $ ? Would this be the approach?

Comment: As @paw88789 said above, the binomial coefficients don't represent outcomes how you'd like them to. $\binom83$ represents how many ways there are to draw 3 things from a set of 8. This is unrelated to your goal, which is to count the probability that all numbers are greater than 5. This corresponds to (# of outcomes where all rolls are greater than 5)/(# of outcomes) = $3^3 / 8^3 = 27/512$.

Comment: @EmmaVaze it should be $\binom{3}{1}\times\binom{3}{1}\times\binom{3}{1}$. From 3 numbers greater than 5, you choose 1 to be the outcome of each of three rolls

Comment: @singerng So here $3^{3}$ stands for 3 rolls or 3 numbers(6,7,8)?

Answer (score 0):

> A eight sided dice is rolled thrice and the first roll was an odd number. We now select (randomly) one of the three rolls, what is the probability that it is an odd number?

Take $X$ as the die selected (1,2, or 3 with equal probability), and $\mathcal O_{\small X}$ as the event of that die showing an odd numbered face.  Events $\mathcal O_1$, $\mathcal O_2$, and $\mathcal O_3$ are pairwise independent, and each also independent of which die is choosen. The condition is that $\mathcal O_1$ occurs. Use the Law of Total Probability to evaluate $\mathsf P(\mathcal O_{\small X}\mid\mathcal O_1)$.

$$\mathsf P(\mathcal O_{\small X}\mid\mathcal O_1)=\mathsf P(X{=}1,\mathcal O_{1}\mid \mathcal O_X)+\mathsf P(X{\neq}1,\mathcal O_{\small X}\mid\mathcal O_1)$$